# Can I obtain the result string used for comparisons with CompareOptions?

Tags: c#, .net, string, icomparer

I have custom `IComparer<string>` which I use to compare strings ignoring their case and symbols like this:

```
public class LiberalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly CompareInfo _compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
    private const CompareOptions COMPARE_OPTIONS = CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols | CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null) return -1;
        if (y == null) return 1;

        return this._compareInfo.Compare(x, y, COMPARE_OPTIONS);
    }
}
```

Can I obtain the output string which is, ultimately, used for the comparison?

My final goal is to produce an `IEqualityComparer<string>` which ignores symbols and casing in the same way as this comparer.

I can write regex to do this, but there's no guarantee that my regex will use the same logic as the built-in comparison options do.

Comment: If you're interested in just `Equals` you can do `yourComparer.Compare(x,y) == 0`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes but that doesn't fulfill all the requirements of `IEqualityComparer` ... I still will need `GetHashCode`

Comment: Is it possible that the strings should be parsed into a new, consistent structure (or converted to a consistent sort of string) in a certain way *before* comparing them? It'd make all of this much simpler, conceptually.

Comment: @TimS. I believe that your answer relies upon that very approach! The reality in that case would be that I wouldn't be able to use the built-in rules for the parsing but would use my own well-defined rules.

Comment: In a sense, but if you can move the logic from comparing with your options to parsing in a way you know, and then represent it in a simpler fashion, then understanding and comparing your data could become much simpler. I don't know what your data represents, but e.g. if it were dollar/currency amounts, you might parse them as `decimal` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably not such an "output string". I'd implement your `Equals` in this way:

```
return liberalStringComparer.Compare(x, y) == 0;
```

`GetHashCode` is more complicated.

Some approaches:

1. Use a poor implementation like `return 0;` (which means you always have to run a `Compare` to know if they're equal).
2. Since your comparison is relatively simple (invariant culture, ordinal ignore case comparison), you should be able to make a hash that generally works. Without extensive study of Unicode and testing, however, I wouldn't recommend that you assume this'll work for *any* valid Unicode string from any culture.

   In pseudocode:

   ```
   public int GetHashCode(string value)
   {
       // for each index in value
       if (!char.IsSymbol(value, i))
           // add value[i].ToUpperInvariant() to the hash using an algorithm
           // like http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/781792
   }
   ```
3. Form a string by removing all where `char.IsSymbol` is `true`, then use [`StringComparer.InvariantCulture.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a04941bd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on it.
4. [`CompareInfo.GetSortKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7ecsckw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s hash code should be a suitable value.

   ```
   public int GetHashCode(string value)
   {
       return _compareInfo.GetSortKey(value, COMPARE_OPTIONS).GetHashCode();
   }
   ```

Comment: I suppose I could remove all chars which return `true` for `char.IsSymbol || char.IsWhiteSpace` and then perform a `CultureInvariantIgnoreCase.GetHashCode` on those resulting strings... Alternatively I could use the `GetUnicodeCategory` method and explicitly exclude categories.

Comment: It appears that `char.IsSymbol` doesn't return true for whitespace. I think, instead, I want to explicitly include things which are `char.IsLetterOrDigit`

Comment: I selected this answer because I had to create my own reliable string procesor to remove spaces and symbols, then I used the CultureInvariantCaseInsensitive solution which is built-in

Answer (score 2):

Quite interesting question here. Internally [CompareInfo.Compare](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs#0cba7af692b66098#references) uses `InternalCompareString` method importing `COMNlsInfo::InternalCompareString` from `clr.dll`:

```
// Compare a string using the native API calls -- COMNlsInfo::InternalCompareString   
...
private static extern int InternalCompareString(IntPtr handle, 
             IntPtr handleOrigin, String localeName, String string1, int offset1, 
             int length1, String string2, int offset2, int length2, int flags);
```

In other words, as you can't be sure about the logic of the built-in function, maybe you should write your own and reuse it in both `IEqualityComparer` and `IComparer` implementations.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that I can't reliably replicate the built-in function, and should use a custom and well-defined `IComparer<string>` and `IEqualityComparer<string>`