# I need to strip all the symbols from a string in order to create an `IEqualityComparer` that ignores punctuation symbols

Tags: c#, string, iequalitycomparer

In part of my application I have an option that displays a list of albums by the current artist that aren't in the music library. To get this I call a music API to get the list of all albums by that artist and then I remove the albums that are in the current library.

To cope with the different casing of names and the possibility of missing (or extra punctuation) in the title I have written an `IEqualityComparer` to use in the `.Except` call:

```
var missingAlbums = allAbumns.Except(ownedAlbums, new NameComparer());
```

This is the `Equals` method:

```
public bool Equals(string x, string y)
{
    // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

    // Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
    if (x is null || y is null)
        return false;

    return string.Compare(x, y, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols) == 0;
}
```

This is the `GetHashCode` method:

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
    // Check whether the object is null
    if (obj is null) return 0;

    // Make lower case. How do I strip symbols?
    return obj.ToLower().GetHashCode();
}
```

This fails, of course, when the string contains symbols as I'm not removing them before getting the hash code so the two strings (e.g. "Baa, baa, black sheep" and "Baa baa Black sheep") are still not equal even after converting to lower case.

I have written a method that will strip the symbols, but that meant I had to guess what those symbols actually are. It works for the cases I've tried so far, but I'm expecting it to fail eventually. I'd like a more reliable method of removing the symbols.

Given that the `CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols` exists, is there a method I can call that will strip these characters from a string? Or failing that, a method that will return all the symbols?

I have found the [`IsPunctuation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.ispunctuation?view=net-5.0) method for characters, but I can't determine whether what this deems to be punctuation is the same as what the string compare option deems to be a symbol.

Comment: Do you want to remove all symbols of a string? Keeping only letters? Eventually numbers too to allow *Element3*? Or only certains chars like comma and semilicon to keep for example *Simon & Garfunkel*?

Comment: @OlivierRogier I need to remove all the symbols that are ignored when you use the `CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols` flag on `string.Compare`. `GetHashCode` has to return the same value for two strings that would be deemed the same by the comparison.

Comment: Related: [Can I obtain the result string used for comparisons with CompareOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23118292) Some good (underrated) answers there. Konrad's is basically what first popped into my mind: "I'll bet that API is calling down to a native Win32 API which you could call directly. Let someone else do the tracking of what is and is not punctuation." Perhaps the best answer is to P/Invoke [`LCMapStringEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-lcmapstringex) (if it's not already wrapped) with the `NORM_IGNORESYMBOLS` flag.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of diamonds and rep floating around this question and its answer and comments.

Comment: @Flydog57: just goes to show, us newbies can still teach the old dogs a few new tricks. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're going to use the [`CompareOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions) enum, I feel like you might as well use it with the [`CompareInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo) class that it's documented as being designed for:

> Defines the string comparison options to use with [CompareInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo).

Then you can just use the [`GetHashCode(string, CompareOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.gethashcode#System_Globalization_CompareInfo_GetHashCode_System_String_System_Globalization_CompareOptions_) method from that class (and even the [`Compare(string, string, CompareOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.compare#System_Globalization_CompareInfo_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Globalization_CompareOptions_) method if you like).